# How to temporarily disable foreign keys in Amazon RDS Aurora PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, foreign-key, amazon-rds, aws

Hi I am using DMS to load data from physical server to AWS Aurora PostgreSQL, but I am getting error for foreign key constraint.

I want to disable using any sp / function. Could you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Foreign keys are *not* there to get in your way and "annoy" you.
They are there to protect the relational integrity of the data in your tables.

A simplistic example - you cannot have an Order_Line record that doesn't have a corresponding Order_Header record.

Look at the data you are trying to load and find out why it doesn't "fit" with what the constraint is enforcing.
You may need to change the *order* in which DMS is loading your tables.